# Como herdar uma classe pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, herança, pygame

Quando eu executo este código (este é o código inteiro atual, ou seja, apenas 3 linhas):

```
import pygame
class sp(pygame.sprite):
    pass
```

Eu recebo:

> TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Eu gostaria de herdar esta classe para criar alguns objetos adicionais nela, bem como executar algumas das funções já existentes.

Por exemplo, ao invés de ...

```
mysprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Eu quero...

```
mysprites = sp.Group()
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você **não pode** criar uma classe filha de um módulo. O sistema de herança só funciona de classe pra classe, e **módulos não são classes**. São objetos, instâncias da classe `module`.

O que você disse que quer no fim da pergunta não precisa de herança, pode ser feito assim:

```
from pygame import sprite as sp
mysprites = sp.Group()
```

Se quiser, por algum motivo criar uma classe filha de `sprite.Group` você pode, principalmente porque **`sprite.Group` é uma classe**:

```
class MyGroup(sp.Group):
    ...
```

Porém **herdar de um módulo** como disse no início da resposta, não é algo que faça sentido na linguagem.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu disse, eu gostaria de herdar esta classe para criar alguns objetos adicionais nela... como fazer neste caso?

Comment: @RogérioDec A resposta está clara - não é possível "herdar esta classe" porque `sprite` é um módulo e não uma classe - e "herdar" só funciona com classes.

Comment: Talvez pense em uma outra forma de fazer o que você quer - provavelmente não é preciso herdar nada pra fazer. Lembre-se de que python é diferente de linguagens como java onde cada arquivo é uma classe e tudo precisa ser classes. Em python isso é simplificado, você pode ter funções soltas e usar os módulos à vontade.

Comment: -1 - tanto o autor, quanto o que faz sentido em Pygame é herdr da classe sprite - só um uso bem avançado em projeto grande vai precisar herdar sprite.Groups para criar qualquer coisa nova. Já herdar de sprite.Sprite é feito para o uso normal de pygame: a  ideia é que os objetos a serem exibidos na tela definidos no código do usuário execute algum código de inicialização e mantenha alguns estados internos para funcionar bem com os varios tipos de `pygame.sprite.Group` pré-definidos.

Comment: @jsbueno não estou sugerindo que o OP herde de `Group` pra algum motivo. Estou somente dizendo que só é possível herdar de classes, e nunca de módulos. Acho que você foi precipitado em dar -1 para a resposta, que está correta. Leia novamente

Comment: não tem nada precipitado aí - o errado é dar menos 1 para a resposta correta por "vingança" - se você tivesse familiaridade com a biblioteca ou olhasse a documentação, veria que o AP confundiu o módulo com a classe. Você poderia ao menos por a frase "você provavelemente confundiu "pygame.sprite.Sprite" com "pygame.sprite".   - Em vez disso, sugere uma herança que, correta em termos de OOP, em termos práticos ao faze um projeto de pygame, não tem sentido para iniciantes. Eu não considero que essa resposta esteja correta.

Comment: @jsbueno bom, não fui eu que dei -1 para sua resposta, que na minha opinião apesar de correta não responde a pergunta feita pelo OP, por isso também não dei +1, mas não acho que ela mereça -1.

Comment: @jsbueno Mas é assim mesmo, por isso existe o sistema de votação - nem todo mundo vai concordar aqui, então cada um dá o voto que acha melhor.

Answer (score 0):

A classe que você deve herdar em Pygame para uso noral da bibioteca é `pygame.sprite.Sprite` -  o problema que você teve foi só de confundir `pygame.sprite` que é o módulo, com `pygame.sprite.Sprite` que é a classe `Sprite` dentro do módulo.

Herdando dessa classe *e* chamando o método `__init__` das superclasses, seus objetos vão funcionar com os grupos e todos os métodos neles, como está na documentação.

```
import pygame
class sp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
         ...
```

Quanto a sua segunda pergunta, é natural querer encurtar o que se digita, e Python permite isso, inclusive com três formas diferentes do comando `import`.

Em vez de

```
import pygame
a = = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

você pode fazer:

from pygame.sprite import Group
   a = Group()

ou

```
import pygame.sprite as sp
a = sp.Group()
```